# Different behaviour of intersect on vectors and factors

Tags: r

I try to compare multiple vectors of Entrez IDs (integer vectors) by using Reduce(intersect,...). The vectors are selected from a database using "DISTINCT" so a single vector does not contain duplicates.

```
length(factor(c(l1$entrez)))
```

gives the same length (and the same IDs w/o the length function) as

```
length(c(l1$entrez))
```

When I compare multiple vectors with

```
length(Reduce(intersect,list(c(l1$entrez),c(l2$entrez),c(l3$entrez),c(l4$entrez))))
```

or

```
length(Reduce(intersect,list(c(factor(l1$entrez)),c(factor(l2$entrez)),c(factor(l3$entrez)),c(factor(l4$entrez)))))
```

the result is not the same. I know that factor!=originalVector but I cannot understand why the result differs although the length and the levels of the initial factors/vectors are the same.

Could somebody please explain the different behaviour of the intersect function on vectors and factors? Is it that the intersect of two factor lists are again factorlists and then duplicates are treated differently?

Edit - Example:

```
> head(l1)
  entrez
1      1
2 503538
3  29974
4  87769
5      2
6 144568

> head(l2)
 entrez
1  1743
2  1188
3  8915
4  7412
5 51082
6  5538
```

The lists contain around 500 to 20K Entrez IDs. So the vectors contain pure integer and should give the intersect among all tested vectors.

```
> length(Reduce(intersect,list(c(factor(l1$entrez)),c(factor(l2$entrez)),c(factor(l3$entrez)),c(factor(l4$entrez)))))
[1] 514
> length(Reduce(intersect,list(c(l1$entrez),c(l2$entrez),c(l3$entrez),c(l4$entrez))))
[1] 338
> length(Reduce(intersect,list(l1$entrez,l2$entrez,l3$entrez,l4$entrez)))
[1] 494
```

**I have to apologize profusely. The different behaviour of the intersect function may be caused by a problem with the data. I have found fields in the dataset containing comma seperated Entrez IDs (22038, 23207, ...). I should have had a more detailed look at the data first. Thank you for the answers and your time. Although I do not understand the different results yet, I am sure that this is the cause of the different behaviour. Can somebody confirm that?**

Comment: Can't speak for others, but a reproducible example would help immensely.

Comment: Thanks for the comment: An example for the lists I am trying to compare:

Comment: Is ID a factor or an integer variable though? If you imported it from a database, and that database stores ID as character (which is reasonable, because it's not a variable for which numerical operations make sense) then it would import as factor.

Comment: In the database the Entrez ID is stored as varchar but in R all IDs are recognized as integer: > typeof(l1$entrez)
[1] "integer"

Answer (score 0):

As Roman says, an example would be very helpful.

Nevertheless, one possibility is that your variables `l1$entrez`, `l2$entrez` etc have the same levels but in different orders.

`intersect` converts its arguments via `as.vector`, which turns factors into character variables. This is usually the right thing to do, as it means that varying level order doesn't make any difference to the result.

Passing `factor(l1$entrez)` as an argument to `intersect` also removes the impact of varying level order, as it effectively creates a new factor with level ordering set to the default. However, if you pass `c(l1$entrez)`, you strip the factor attributes off your variable and what you're left with is the raw integer codes which will depend on level ordering.

Example:

```
a <- factor(letters[1:3], levels=letters)
b <- factor(letters[1:3], levels=rev(letters)

# returns 1 2 3
intersect(c(factor(a)), c(factor(b)))

# returns integer(0)
intersect(c(a), c(b))
```

I don't see any reason why you should use `c()` in here. Just let R handle factors by itself (although to be fair, there are other scenarios where you do want to step in).

Comment: Thank you very much Hong! Your answer doesn´t help to free me of all confusion but helps a lot anyway. To add another layer of confusion I can give a third way of calculating intersects which gives ANOTHER result set (third result), without using factor() or c():     length(Reduce(intersect,list(l1$entrez,l2$entrez,l3$entrez,l4$entrez
                             )) . I tried this after you suggested not to use c() (which is of course completely correct). I used c() because of an example I found for using Reduced().